# Jest: Is there a way to return a pass or fail value from a Jest expect?

Tags: typescript, ts-jest, testrail

I've been working on integrating TestRail with my test automation and had a question. I have everything hooked up and working through the TestRail API but I don't really know how to return or save the pass/fail value of my test so I can mark my test cases correctly. Has anyone been through this and found a solution?

My ideal flow is:

Run test.

Somehow save/return pass or fail value of test.

Use that value to update the status of my test case via TestRail API.

Thanks!